# Открытие приложения по ссылке в браузере

Tags: c#, winforms, uri

Делаю winform приложение. Мне нужно чтобы на сайте можно было встроить ссылку при нажатии на которую будет открываться мое приложение. Я нашел в интернете решение с URI и примеры для консольного приложения. Как я понял надо встроить ссылку на сайт, внести данные в реестр и тд. Но я не понял как передавать данные самому приложению (например данные о пользователе). Объясните пожалуйста как это должно работать, что добавить в само winform приложение и в ссылку чтобы передавать данные приложению.

Код тестового приложения на виндформ:

```cs
static string ProcessInput(string s)
{
    // TODO Verify and validate the input 
    // string as appropriate for your application.
    return s;
}

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    string ab;
    ab = "";
    string[] args = new string[100];
    foreach (string s in args)
    {
        ab +=  Convert.ToString(ProcessInput(s));
    }

    textBox4.Text = ab;
}
```

Ссылка:

```html
<a href="prog:"> Open folder </a>
```

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\prog]
@="URL:prog Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\prog\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\prog\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\prog\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\winform\\WinFormsApp1.exe\" \"%1\"\""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Берете любую строчку

Например

```
Hello world!
```

Кодируете ее в Base64, используйте исходный текст в кодировке UTF-8

```
SGVsbG8gd29ybGQh
```

подставляете в ссылку

```html
<a href="prog:SGVsbG8gd29ybGQh"> Open folder </a>
```

В приложении получаете аргументы

```cs
string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
if (args.Length > 0)
{
    string commandCode = args[^1]; // prog:SGVsbG8gd29ybGQh
    if (commandCode.StartsWith("prog:"))
    {
        string command = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(commandCode.Split(':')[1])); // Hello World!
        MessageBox.Show(command);
    }
}
```

Не используйте коструктор формы для написания своего кода. Используйте вместо этого обработчик события формы `Form.Load`

Comment: Ошибка CS1503 Аргумент 1: не удается преобразовать из "byte[]" в "char[]".
string command = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Convert.FromBase64String(commandCode)); // Hello World!

Comment: @ChpFox опечатался, исправил

Comment: Исправил и пишет эту ошибку. System.FormatException: "The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters."

Comment: @ChpFox Вы посмотрите в отладке, что содержит `commandCode`, вообще содержимое массива `args` изучите.

Comment: @ChpFox быть может надо кавычки отрезать `string commandCode = args[0].Trim('"');`

Comment: commandCode содержит commandCode "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\VS projects\\WinFormsApp1\\WinFormsApp1\\bin\\Debug\\net5.0-windows\\WinFormsApp1.dll" string , а комманд пустой. Пробовал компилировать и запускать через ссылку в браузере, тоже пишет ошибку.

Comment: @ChpFox а в остальном массиве что?

Comment: в самом args C:\Users\User\Desktop\VS projects\WinFormsApp1\WinFormsApp1\bin\Debug\net5.0-windows\WinFormsApp1.dll @aepot

Comment: @ChpFox а если в args из Program.cs Main заглянуть? Быть может у вас в реестре что-то не то и система просто не передает аргумент.

Comment: а как из Program.cs посмотреть?

Comment: заменил args[0] на args[1] и добавил в отладчике аргумент командной строки и программа заработала. Но при попытке ее открытия через ссылку в браузере, не работает.

Comment: Все, нашел проблему. Аргумент передавал не только текст "SGVsbG8gd29ybGQh" но еще и "prog:". Отрезал начало и все заработало. Спасибо.

Comment: @ChpFox отлично, я поправил код в ответе, чтобы брался последний аргумент и отрезался `prog:`. Так же можете обернуть весь блок работы с аргументами в `try-catch`, чтобы приложение не крашилось в случае если в аргументах ошибка.